# django, a good way of querying a distinct model

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

Assume I have a such model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("ad",max_length=25)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
```

So at the database I have Foo objects with same name field but different types ie:

```
name type
A     1
A     2
B     1
C     2
A     3
B     3
```

I will use this information inorder to generate a html select form, displaying all possible (distinct) names so in the end my select form will be showing such:

```
<select>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

How do I get a list of distinct values for `name`?

Comment: Am I the only one that doesn't see any question here :) ?

Comment: @Tomasz - there's one there if you look for it, I've edited it in to make it more apparent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In answer to your subsequent question to Till, an easier way is:

```
Foo.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct().order_by('name')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Foo.objects.values('name').distinct().order_by('name')
```

Comment: this seem to work thanks but the output is such:

{'name': u'A}
{'name': u'B}
{'name': u'C}

how can I fix this problem ?

Comment: for the record I have it such: names = [i["name"] for i in Foo.objects.values('name').distinct().order_by('name')]

Comment: See my answer for an easier way to do this.